# Can't compare string turned into integer java

Tags: java, android, string, if-statement, int

So, I need to change my textView color to red if it's more than 0 and to green if it's less than 0, but I can't write if statement properly, because textView is a string, but I've changed it to int.

```
textView.setText(textView + "");


        if(textView > 0) {
            textView.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        }
        else if (textView < 0){
            textView.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
         }
        else {
            textView.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

    }
```

Comment: `textView` appears to be a GUI component.  You are calling `setText` on it something you can't do with an `int` value.

Comment: reorder it like this: `textView.setText("" + textView);`

Comment: This way implicit conversion will take care of it for you. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with the `String` inside the `TextView` (Which is not a `String`, it's a `View`) you first need to access it with `.getText().toString()`. So if you want to work with the value of the textView like an integer, do the following:

```
String stringValue = textView.getText().toString();
int intValue = Integer.parseInt(stringValue);
//Now do your logic.
```

If you want to set the value again to the view, make sure you're passing a `String` and not an integer.